# PostgreSQL - max(count()) agregation with group by

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregation

I have a table that contains unique transactions along with the year of the transaction and the employee who executed it. I need to find the employee with most transactions in each year.

I need a table with each year, the employee w/ most transactions in that year, and the number of transactions they had in that year.
This is as close as I am able to get without producing an error. I am unable to select the employee without producing an aggregation error.

```
select year, max(num_trans)
from (select year, employee, count(trans_id) as num_trans
      from transactions
      group by year, employee) as x
group by year
```

I am curious about how to work around this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (year) year, employee, count(*) as num_trans
from transactions
group by year, employee
order by year, count(*) desc;
```

`distinct on` is a handy Postgres extension to standard SQL that keeps the first row in a group of rows.  The groups are defined by the `distinct on` key(s).  Which row is first is determined by the `order by`.